# Android: autocompletetextview values from TreeMap keys

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a TreeMap and i want to use the string keys as the autoCompleteTextView string array resource.
Is it possible?
If possible will it be updated every time the i add an entry to the Map?

Comment: sure: the easiest way is to use SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Can you explain a bit. I am an absolute beginner :-)

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara . it uses web response as input data so you need to change it to use your tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he meant how to convert the key set of the map into a string array, so he'll be able to display it in a simple ArrayAdapter and use it in an AutoCompleteTextView

```
    TreeMap<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
    AutoCompleteTextView tv = new AutoCompleteTextView(getActivity());
    String[] yourArray = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourArray);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if he accepted it, he is ok with the fact he lost any benefits of fast data structure that TreeMap is

Comment: @pskink Perhaps you would expand a bit more, on how this is going to help him if he only wants to display a simple string list?